# Erlang: ibrowse - get redirected URL

Tags: erlang

I'm using ibrowse API for Erlang. The problem is that when I try to read webpages that redirect to another webpage it turns up blank. Any ideas on how to follow the trace to the end-page?

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
get_web(Src) ->
    ibrowse:start(),
    {_,_,_,Body} = ibrowse:send_req(Src, [], get),
    Body.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should follow the `Location` header in the response if it has a 301 or 302 status code.

```
get_web({url,Src}) ->
  ibrowse:start(),
  {ok, Status, Head, Body} = ibrowse:send_req(Src, [], get),
  if
    Status =:= 200 ->
      Body;
    Status =:= 301 orelse Status =:= 302 ->
      get_web(get_location(Head))
  end.

get_location(Head) ->
  case lists:keyfind("Location", 1, Head) of
    false -> {url, error};
    URL -> {url, URL}
  end.
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles upon this, here is what I did:

```
get_web({_,error}) ->
    error;

get_web({url,Src}) ->
    ibrowse:start(),
    {_,_,Head,Body} = ibrowse:send_req(Src, [], get),
    if
        length(Body) == 0 ->
            get_web(get_location(Head));
        true ->
            Body
    end.

get_location([]) ->
    {url,error};
get_location([{"Location",URL}|_]) ->
    {url,URL};
get_location([_|T]) ->
    get_location(T).
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, since some websites provide a dummy html snippet with href to the new page for redirects. Better check if the statuscode is `302` and then use the `Location` header. That's what the statuscode is for ;)